# Chainlink Node Setup Error: ChainID doesn't match local chain ID

Tags: chainlink

I'm trying to setup a local instance of a Chainlink Node, but running into errors within the startup script. When I run `./chainlink node start —env-file=.env` I get the following outputs (condensed):

```
2021-10-11T17:02:37Z [INFO]  EVM ChainSet has default chain id: 4 and number of chains: 5 evm/chain_set.go:257
2021-10-11T17:02:37Z [INFO]  EVM ChainSet has default chain id: 4 and number of chains: 5 evm/chain_set.go:257    
2021-10-11T17:02:37Z [INFO]  EVM: Loading chain 1                               evm/chain_set.go:262    
2021-10-11T17:02:37Z [INFO]  EVM: Loading chain 4                               evm/chain_set.go:262    
2021-10-11T17:02:37Z [INFO]  EVM: Loading chain 42                              evm/chain_set.go:262    
2021-10-11T17:02:37Z [INFO]  EVM: Loading chain 13                              evm/chain_set.go:262    
2021-10-11T17:02:37Z [WARN]  Unrecognised chain 13, falling back to generic default configuration config/config.go:99   
2021-10-11T17:02:48Z [INFO]  EVM: Started 5 chains, default chain ID is 4       evm/chain_set.go:57     
error starting app: the following errors occurred:
 -  websocket rpc ChainID doesn't match local chain ID: RPC ID=42, local ID=13, node name=primary-0-13
    github.com/smartcontractkit/chainlink/core/services/eth.node.Verify
        /Users/julian/chainlink/core/services/eth/node.go:397
    github.com/smartcontractkit/chainlink/core/services/eth.(*Pool).verifyChainIDs
        /Users/julian/chainlink/core/services/eth/pool.go:51
    github.com/smartcontractkit/chainlink/core/services/eth.(*Pool).Dial
        /Users/julian/chainlink/core/services/eth/pool.go:43
    github.com/smartcontractkit/chainlink/core/services/eth.(*client).Dial
        /Users/julian/chainlink/core/services/eth/client.go:113
    github.com/smartcontractkit/chainlink/core/chains/evm.(*chain).Start.func1
        /Users/julian/chainlink/core/chains/evm/chain.go:165
    github.com/smartcontractkit/chainlink/core/utils.(*StartStopOnce).StartOnce
        /Users/julian/chainlink/core/utils/utils.go:984
    github.com/smartcontractkit/chainlink/core/chains/evm.(*chain).Start
        /Users/julian/chainlink/core/chains/evm/chain.go:159
    github.com/smartcontractkit/chainlink/core/chains/evm.(*chainSet).Start
        /Users/julian/chainlink/core/chains/evm/chain_set.go:55
    github.com/smartcontractkit/chainlink/core/services/chainlink.(*ChainlinkApplication).Start
        /Users/julian/chainlink/core/services/chainlink/application.go:373
    github.com/smartcontractkit/chainlink/core/cmd.(*Client).RunNode
        /Users/julian/chainlink/core/cmd/local_client.go:144
    github.com/urfave/cli.HandleAction
        /Users/julian/go/pkg/mod/github.com/urfave/cli@v1.22.5/app.go:524
    github.com/urfave/cli.Command.Run
        /Users/julian/go/pkg/mod/github.com/urfave/cli@v1.22.5/command.go:173
    github.com/urfave/cli.(*App).RunAsSubcommand
        /Users/julian/go/pkg/mod/github.com/urfave/cli@v1.22.5/app.go:405
    github.com/urfave/cli.Command.startApp
        /Users/julian/go/pkg/mod/github.com/urfave/cli@v1.22.5/command.go:372
    github.com/urfave/cli.Command.Run
        /Users/julian/go/pkg/mod/github.com/urfave/cli@v1.22.5/command.go:102
    github.com/urfave/cli.(*App).Run
        /Users/julian/go/pkg/mod/github.com/urfave/cli@v1.22.5/app.go:277
    main.Run
        /Users/julian/chainlink/core/main.go:20
    main.main
        /Users/julian/chainlink/core/main.go:14
    runtime.main
        /usr/local/go/src/runtime/proc.go:255
    runtime.goexit
        /usr/local/go/src/runtime/asm_amd64.s:1581
    failed to dial pool
    github.com/smartcontractkit/chainlink/core/services/eth.(*client).Dial
        /Users/julian/chainlink/core/services/eth/client.go:114
    github.com/smartcontractkit/chainlink/core/chains/evm.(*chain).Start.func1
        /Users/julian/chainlink/core/chains/evm/chain.go:165
    github.com/smartcontractkit/chainlink/core/utils.(*StartStopOnce).StartOnce
        /Users/julian/chainlink/core/utils/utils.go:984
    github.com/smartcontractkit/chainlink/core/chains/evm.(*chain).Start
        /Users/julian/chainlink/core/chains/evm/chain.go:159
    github.com/smartcontractkit/chainlink/core/chains/evm.(*chainSet).Start
        /Users/julian/chainlink/core/chains/evm/chain_set.go:55
    github.com/smartcontractkit/chainlink/core/services/chainlink.(*ChainlinkApplication).Start
        /Users/julian/chainlink/core/services/chainlink/application.go:373
    github.com/smartcontractkit/chainlink/core/cmd.(*Client).RunNode
        /Users/julian/chainlink/core/cmd/local_client.go:144
    github.com/urfave/cli.HandleAction
        /Users/julian/go/pkg/mod/github.com/urfave/cli@v1.22.5/app.go:524
    github.com/urfave/cli.Command.Run
        /Users/julian/go/pkg/mod/github.com/urfave/cli@v1.22.5/command.go:173
    github.com/urfave/cli.(*App).RunAsSubcommand
        /Users/julian/go/pkg/mod/github.com/urfave/cli@v1.22.5/app.go:405
    github.com/urfave/cli.Command.startApp
        /Users/julian/go/pkg/mod/github.com/urfave/cli@v1.22.5/command.go:372
    github.com/urfave/cli.Command.Run
        /Users/julian/go/pkg/mod/github.com/urfave/cli@v1.22.5/command.go:102
    github.com/urfave/cli.(*App).Run
        /Users/julian/go/pkg/mod/github.com/urfave/cli@v1.22.5/app.go:277
    main.Run
        /Users/julian/chainlink/core/main.go:20
    main.main
        /Users/julian/chainlink/core/main.go:14
    runtime.main
        /usr/local/go/src/runtime/proc.go:255
    runtime.goexit
        /usr/local/go/src/runtime/asm_amd64.s:1581
    failed to Dial ethclient
    github.com/smartcontractkit/chainlink/core/chains/evm.(*chain).Start.func1
        /Users/julian/chainlink/core/chains/evm/chain.go:166
    github.com/smartcontractkit/chainlink/core/utils.(*StartStopOnce).StartOnce
        /Users/julian/chainlink/core/utils/utils.go:984
    github.com/smartcontractkit/chainlink/core/chains/evm.(*chain).Start
        /Users/julian/chainlink/core/chains/evm/chain.go:159
    github.com/smartcontractkit/chainlink/core/chains/evm.(*chainSet).Start
        /Users/julian/chainlink/core/chains/evm/chain_set.go:55
    github.com/smartcontractkit/chainlink/core/services/chainlink.(*ChainlinkApplication).Start
        /Users/julian/chainlink/core/services/chainlink/application.go:373
    github.com/smartcontractkit/chainlink/core/cmd.(*Client).RunNode
        /Users/julian/chainlink/core/cmd/local_client.go:144
    github.com/urfave/cli.HandleAction
        /Users/julian/go/pkg/mod/github.com/urfave/cli@v1.22.5/app.go:524
    github.com/urfave/cli.Command.Run
        /Users/julian/go/pkg/mod/github.com/urfave/cli@v1.22.5/command.go:173
    github.com/urfave/cli.(*App).RunAsSubcommand
        /Users/julian/go/pkg/mod/github.com/urfave/cli@v1.22.5/app.go:405
    github.com/urfave/cli.Command.startApp
        /Users/julian/go/pkg/mod/github.com/urfave/cli@v1.22.5/command.go:372
    github.com/urfave/cli.Command.Run
        /Users/julian/go/pkg/mod/github.com/urfave/cli@v1.22.5/command.go:102
    github.com/urfave/cli.(*App).Run
        /Users/julian/go/pkg/mod/github.com/urfave/cli@v1.22.5/app.go:277
    main.Run
        /Users/julian/chainlink/core/main.go:20
    main.main
        /Users/julian/chainlink/core/main.go:14
    runtime.main
        /usr/local/go/src/runtime/proc.go:255
    runtime.goexit
        /usr/local/go/src/runtime/asm_amd64.s:1581
     -  websocket rpc ChainID doesn't match local chain ID: RPC ID=4, local ID=44, node name=primary-0-44
 -  dial tcp [::1]:8546: connect: connection refused
    Error while dialing websocket: ws://localhost:8546
 -  websocket rpc ChainID doesn't match local chain ID: RPC ID=4, local ID=42, node name=primary-0-42
```

My .env file explicitly states that I want a Rinkeby websocket

```
ETH_URL=wss://rinkeby.infura.io/ws/v3/b1dd56f69a7447eab07e12618a9cc712
ETH_CHAIN_ID=4
LINK_CONTRACT_ADDRESS=0x01BE23585060835E02B77ef475b0Cc51aA1e0709
DATABASE_URL=postgresql://localhost:5432/julian?sslmode=disable
LOG_LEVEL=debug
```

I'm not sure why the script is trying to load 5 different chains. As soon as I add `ETH_DISABLED=true` I get a running node, so I know this is my final blocker.

Comment: It seems like [chain_set.go](https://github.com/smartcontractkit/chainlink/blob/4ce73a3fce0149632b4a7c712d9123d5ca858a93/core/chains/evm/chain_set.go) is loading multiple chains, while the [Chainlink documentation](https://docs.chain.link/docs/configuration-variables/#eth_chain_id) suggests that only one chain is used. I'm not sure why the script is grabbing multiple chains, and where it's grabbing them from.

Comment: Hmm... this looks like it would be better as an issue on the chainlink github repo https://github.com/smartcontractkit/chainlink

Comment: Okay I posted an [issue](https://github.com/smartcontractkit/chainlink/issues/5211)

Answer (score 2):

My config file was erroneously storing multiple ETH_CHAIN_ID values. Using a clean Postgres database resolved the issue.